# Keep all rows that contain certain phrases

Tags: r, dplyr, filter, grepl

I have a large dataset that contains web domains. The domains end in a number of different top level domains such as .com, .app, .now and so on. I used the code below as i only want to keep the domains that end in the four below. However, when i run the code it keeps any domains that have the words com, net, tv or org. It seems to ignore the period. What can i use so it picks up on the period and only keeps the domains that end in the four below?

```
test <- new_df %>%
  filter(grepl('.com|.net|.tv|.org', domain))
```

Comment: Escape the period with backslashes. `grepl('\\.com|\\.net|\\.tv|\\.org', domain)`. Otherwise regex thinks the period means "match any character"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In regex, "." means any character. If you really want a dot, you need to escape if

```r
grepl('\\.com|\\.net|\\.tv|\\.org', c("jfkdjkfd.com", "jdksjkdscom")) # TRUE FALSE
```